# Overloading get function in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R (<2weeks) but have decades of programming experience that I am trying to translate into this new (for me) world.

I am trying to create a quick/dirty hash table based on environments. Yes, I could probably use the hash package on CRAN, but I'm trying to use this as a learning experience to better understand environments, methods, closures, etc.

My first cut looks like this:

```
#' Simple Map (hash Table)
#'
#' This function creates an empty hash table.
#' @export
map <- function()
{
  self <- environment()   # this/self in other OO languages
  data <- new.env()       # where the key/value pairs will be stored
  class(self) <- c( class(self), 'map' )
  return(self)
}

#' Print map
#' @export
print.map <- function(m)
{
  k <- ls(m$data)
  n <- length(k)
  cat('map with',n,ifelse(n==1,'key:','keys:'),k,'\n')
}

#' @export
get <- function(m,key) 
{ 
  print('get:: class(key):',class(key)); 
  UseMethod('get',m)
}

#' @export
get.map  <- function(m,key) 
{ 
  k <- as.character(key)
  print(paste('get.map:: key:',k))
  get(k,m$data)                    # <------ problem is here
}
```

I realize that in this example, I'm not actually adding any real new functionality that couldn't be handled with an unadulterated environment.  But, my plan is to add additional attributes/methods to self that I don't want colliding with the data in the hash.

So... what's my issue?

I would like provide a method named get, but this is blocking me from invoking the base get function on the data attribute.  I seem to need to provide a generic get function in order for the get.map to be found.  But the existence of this generic appears to be masking the base get function that I need for accessing the content of data.

Is there a way to get around this (i.e. have my get.map method call the base get function)?  Or am I just SOL and need to use a method name other than get?

Example 1: using code as shown above
[image]

Example 2: commenting out my generic print function
[image]

Thanks much!

Comment: Define `get.default <- base::get`. You can also use `base::get` in your `get.map` function but you should always define a default method if you create a generic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the order of the class of the object. When looking at methods, it will look at the first element of the class and so on. When using the map function, if you set up as below it should work for you:

```
map <- function() {
  self <- environment()   # this/self in other OO languages
  data <- new.env()       # where the key/value pairs will be stored
  class(self) <- c('map', class(self))
  return(self)
}
```